# -2 Reputation for "Removed"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation

I lost 2 reputation points because a question was removed. I didn't asked that question. So these are my guesses:

1.-I gave an answer to that question.
2.-I edited that question.
3.-I upvoted that question.

But I can't remember. Its not the only one. I have got this like 3 times total. The reputation help page doesn't say anything about it https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

What is the reason? and someone should totally add that to that help page :)

Comment: You don't get reputation for voting on a question. You probably edited the question.

Comment: There are only two things that give you +2: editing, and accepting an answer. If you had accepted an answer you could see the question under "recently deleted questions" on your profile. So you must have suggested an edit, and now those points are gone with the post.

Comment: (to be fair you might have got +2 from 1 upvote and 4 downvotes, but then you would probably remember it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You had an approved suggest edit on a question that was deleted.

With the question being deleted, any reputation associated with it has gone, hence, it is as if you had never earned that reputation to begin with.

Comment: Makes sense. I thought it was some kind of punishment for upvoting or anwering a bad question. But its as simple as that.

Comment: @Lestat - Simply upvoting stuff would not cause this, as there is no reputation gained for upvotes. And for answers - downvotes would cause reputation loss, but you would see that. There is a _small_ change of having an answer with 1 upvote and 4 downvotes getting deleted (+10 -8 = +2 which gets reverted), but this is rather unlikely.